# Align items baseline for multi-line text

Tags: html, css, flexbox

In a flex container, I have two bits of content. Both sides contain multiple lines of text. I wish to line up the baseline of the top lines of both sides. I've turned to `align-items: baseline` to achieve this, but unfortunately, it doesn't really produce the intended result. Sometimes the browser just plain doesn't seem to align them at all. You can see the different outcomes below:

Misaligned:

```html
<div style="display:flex;align-items:baseline">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>text</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>text2</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div>text3</div>
</div>
```

Top:

```html
<div style="display:flex;align-items:baseline">
  <div>
    <div>text</div>
    <div>text2</div>
  </div>
  <div>text3</div>
</div>
```

Ideally, I'd like to be able to simply indicate the elements containing the text whose baseline I wish to align. But I would probably settle for any solution that always aligns the baseline of the top line of the text on each side.

Currently, I don't use `align-items: baseline` and I simply throw on a magic amount of padding to make them align, which is less than ideal. How can I make the browser align them for me?

Comment: what exactly do you want to align? all texts? nested items have their own positioning scheme and alignment, what do you expect?

Comment: I want to align the baselines of the top line of text on both sides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that [table cells have `vertical-align: middle` by default](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33487148/1529630).

Therefore, you should switch it to `baseline`:

```css
#wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: baseline;
}
td {
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* Some additional styles to display the baseline: */ td { font-size: 200%; } #wrapper:after { content: ''; position: absolute; left: 0; right: 0; border-top: 1px solid red; }
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <table>
    <tr><td>text</td></tr>
    <tr><td>text2</td></tr>
  </table>
  <div>text3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: LOL!!! I totally forgot that `vertical-align` has a `baseline` value. I just used `text-top` which works, as well. Thanks for the reminder +1.

Comment: @Michael_B I guess it's easy to forget, because (usually) it's the default value

Comment: Yes, I see that now. `baseline` is the initial value for `vertical-align` when dealing with inline elements. However, as you suggest in your comment and state in your answer, `middle` is the default value for table cells. I'm sure you're correct because both answers prove that. However, I just searched and couldn't find any officical documentation for this initial value. I checked [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) and the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html), but didn't see anything. Where does it say this?

Comment: @Michael_B Technically, the initial value of [`vertical-align`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align) is always `baseline`. However, [user agents must apply a default style sheet](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#cascade), which is implementation dependent. CSS2.1 [recommends](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/sample.html) using `tbody{vertical-align: middle} td{vertical-align: inherit}` there.

Comment: Ah, it's a UA style. Very interesting. Thank you for that clarification.

Comment: And here's the W3C default stylesheet recommendation, with `vertical-align: middle` on table cells: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/sample.html

Comment: What's really fascinating about this answer is that setting vertical-align: baseline did absolutely nothing to the text inside the table cells, but only fixed the flex alignment. I will experiment to see if we can get away with applying this.

Comment: I'm creating a record of this information. Feel free to provide an answer if you like. http://stackoverflow.com/q/33487148/3597276