# Default value of vertical-align for table cells

Tags: html, css, html-table, vertical-alignment

According to the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align), the default value of `vertical-align` is `baseline`.

> [***`baseline`***](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align)
>
> Align the baseline of the box with the baseline of the parent box. If
>   the box does not have a baseline, align the bottom margin edge with
>   the parent's baseline.

However, when it comes to table cells (`td`) it appears the default value is always `middle`.

> [***`middle`***](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align)
>
> Align the vertical midpoint of the box with the baseline of the parent
>   box plus half the x-height of the parent.

I would like official confirmation of this behavior, but I can't find anything in W3C documentation. Everything I've found says the default value is `baseline`.

Where does it say that the default value of `vertical-align` is `middle` for table cells?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As said by the spec, the initial value of [`vertical-align`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align) is always `baseline`:

> **vertical-align**
>
> - *Initial*: baseline

However, as explained in [The cascade](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#cascade),

> [Conforming user agents](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/conform.html#conformance) must apply a *default style sheet* (or
>   behave as if they did).
>
> A user agent's default style sheet should present the elements of the
>   document language in ways that satisfy general presentation
>   expectations for the document language.
>
> See [A sample style sheet for HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/sample.html) for a recommended default style
>   sheet for HTML documents.

And that recommended stylesheet contains

```css
thead, tbody,
tfoot           { vertical-align: middle }
td, th, tr      { vertical-align: inherit }
```

Therefore, if you (author origin) don't provide any value for `tbody`'s nor `td`'s `vertical-align`, the cascade will retrieve the `middle` value from the user agent origin.

Note the default style sheet is implementation dependent, so some browsers may set different `vertical-align` values for different elements.

Comment: Oh, that explains why `td { vertical-align:initial; }` reverts things back to `baseline` (I struggled understanding why because I thought `middle` was the default value so `initial` would keep it as is)