# Vertical align: default value

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, vertical-alignment

I've just started out learning HTML/CSS. I'm playing around with creating navbars. I've been testing navbars with a logo followed by horizontal navigation (custom, rather than using Bootstrap).

My code seems to always make the logo and nav vertically align in the middle. This is actually what I want - but I don't understand why it does this, as I thought that vertical-align will be baseline unless set otherwise.

I've created three alternative headers:

1. logo vertically aligned baseline
2. logo vertically aligned middle
3. no vertical alignment set (I've set the vertical-align value using inline CSS).

Options (2) and (3) appear the same...and I don't know why. I'd be more than happy for someone to point out the obvious thing I am missing...

```css
.container {
    background-color: #f8f8f8;
}

.header ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-block;
}

.header li {
    display: inline;
}
 
.header a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: grey;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 20px 30px;
}

.header a:hover {
    color: black;
}

.active a {
    background-color: #e7e7e7;
}

.header img {
    margin: 0px 20px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Header Test</title>

<!--External CSS-->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat+Alternates:700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> 

</head>

<body>
<h2>Logo aligned > baseline</h2>
<div class="header">
    <div class="container">
        <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/junction/logo.svg" style="vertical-align: baseline;" height="30" width="30">
        <ul>
     <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
 </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div style="height: 20px;"></div>
<h2>Logo aligned > middle</h2>
<div class="header">
    <div class="container">
        <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/junction/logo.svg" style="vertical-align: middle;" height="30" width="30">
        <ul>
     <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
 </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div style="height: 20px;"></div>
<h2>No alignment set</h2>
<div class="header">
    <div class="container">
        <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/junction/logo.svg" height="30" width="30">
        <ul>
     <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
 </ul>
    </div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Its because you're using bootstrap and your `img` tag has `vertical-align: middle;` in your bootstrap style sheet.

Comment: In addition to @Anonymous the default value is `baseline` as you think in first instance

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33487148/3597276