# Grid layout being disrupted in Firefox, but not in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

For a school project I have to make a website. The website I have made seems to have it's grid layout displaying incorrectly in Firefox. In chrome/all browsers it should look like this
[image: chrome screenshot]

however in Firefox it is coming up like so,

[image: firefox screenshot]

```
It's almost like there's padding on the container or a margin on the row, but there isn't.
```

[image: img gif]

If anyone could help it would be great. I have added a JSFiddle here, https://jsfiddle.net/o31t9eLb/

Comment: I recommend simplifying your problem to the simplest possible example that demonstrates the problem. Do you need the menus? The title? All that text? Rounded corners? Try removing things until you have just a couple of tags and CSS rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add a `vertical-align: top;` on .sidebar and .container because by default the vertical-align is set to middle.

Reason is well explained here : [Default value of vertical-align for table cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33487148/default-value-of-vertical-align-for-table-cells)