# Table with hide/show div moving wrong div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a PHP script that gets data from a database and displays it in a 2 column table.  I have a hide/show for each of the results, which extends down, pushing any options below it down too when clicked.

However the results in the column on the other-side also move down.

How do I make it so only the column with the clicked hide/show opens and moves down?

Below is the code I am using to show the hide/show; I thought by adding a `.closest('td')` may help, but all it does is open the corresponding left or right hide/show div!

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $(".reveal-arrow").click(function(){
        $(this).parents('.template-container').find('.reveal-container').slideToggle();
        $(this).toggleClass('flip');
    });
});
```

**Update:** I have made a simplified fiddle of whats happening here: https://jsfiddle.net/r1bf4odx/18/

As you can see if you click the down arrow on BOX1 it 1 opens down, however BOX 2 also moves down. How do I stop Box 2 moving and stay where it is! Thanks again!

Please bear in mind that I am getting many results from a database!

Comment: You need to traverse the DOM https://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/ Where you're trying to traverse to depends on your HTML

Comment: Please add an exemplary HTML to your question. If possible, also add the __relevant__ CSS you use. :-)

Comment: This doesn't sound like it has anything to do with PHP. Unless I'm mistaken, when you post your HTML, ensure it's the final HTML and not the PHP code.

Comment: .find() goes down the dom and .closest() goes up the dom, a combination of the both should hopefully resolve this

Comment: Could you post the generated HTML?

Comment: Yes I will post some HTML shortly... just stepped out. I think the problem is that the divs are called the same thing, as they are going into a template from the database.

Comment: @PhilippMaurer I have added a fiddle!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are using a table, and the default alignment for a table is `baseline` / `middle` (see [here (SO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33487148/default-value-of-vertical-align-for-table-cells) for more info).

You can add

```
td { vertical-align: top; }
```

to fix the moving boxes

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/r1bf4odx/21/

Comment: Thanks - thats sort of solved the problem. However the div below is still moving down with the when the drop down opens.. let me see if I can replicate it in a fiddle!

Comment: You'll need to determine how you want to "fix" that, because the 'expanded' div takes up more room, so the lower items need to move down to give it the room it needs.  If it's non-trivial, you might need a new question as this question was specifically for "*results in the **column on the other-side** also move down*".

Comment: Ok, thanks. I think i've confused things! What I mean is if Box 2 is clicked to open, I don't want box 3 to move! Does that make sense! Sorry - Im new to all this. https://jsfiddle.net/r1bf4odx/26/

Comment: Yes, it's clear.  Your question had 1 row - when you expand a box, other boxes on that row were moving.  This answer fixes that.  You now have 2 rows and expanding a box on row1 moves all the boxes on row2 - to make room for row1.  You can fix it by using `position:absolute` (https://jsfiddle.net/r1bf4odx/31/) - it's a bit jerky but you can fix that by removing the `ontop`  class when the animation has completed (which you can't do with `.toggle()`, so left for you).

Comment: Looks good - Thanks! Is it possible to allow Box 2 to shift down, Box 3 to stay where it is when box 1 opens?  Sorry to keep pestering you! learning a lot from all this!

Comment: Not if you're using a `<table>` with rows `<tr>` - the row will always line up.  (I assume you mean the ones under the one expanding to move while other ones on that row don't expand).  It's probably do-able, but not with a table.