# Flexbox in table cell appears in the vertical middle

Tags: html, css, html-table, flexbox

I am using flexbox in a table.
The table has 2 columns, each with one cell.
The left cell is very big, and has a height of maybe 189%.
My CSS is as follows:

```css
#openemail {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 100%;
}

#openemail>#header {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
}

#openemail>#body {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<table id="app">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="emailslist"><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div id="openemail">
        <div id="header">SSS</div>
        <div id="body">more SSS</div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

As you can see, the flex container ends up in the middle, and is hard to find. My question is: how can I change my CSS so that the flex container is at the top of my table cell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would adding vertical-align: top to the table cell do what you want it to do? Like this:

```
<table id="app">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="emailslist"><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/></div>
    </td>
    <td style="vertical-align: top;">
      <div id="openemail"><div id="header">SSS</div><div id="body">more SSS</div></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

**RECOMMENDED:**

Applying `vertical-align: top` to `<td>` seems to be the optimal solution in *2018*, which is fully supported in CSS3 and HTML5. Here's a working sample:

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#openemail {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    height: 100%;
}

#openemail>#header {
    flex: 0 1 auto;
}

#openemail>#body {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

```html
    <table id="app">
<tr>
    <td>
        <div id="emailslist">
            placeholder<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td style="vertical-align: top">
        <div id="openemail"><div id="header">SSS</div><div id="body">more SSS</div></div>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

To learn more about the `vertical-align` style: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_vertical-align.asp

**NOT RECOMMENDED:**

The following solution could also work if you are using older versions of HTML: setting the `valign` attribute of `<td>` to be `top`. It looks something like this:

```css
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#openemail {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    height: 100%;
}

#openemail>#header {
    flex: 0 1 auto;
}

#openemail>#body {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

```html
    <table id="app">
<tr>
    <td>
        <div id="emailslist">
            placeholder<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td valign="top">
        <div id="openemail"><div id="header">SSS</div><div id="body">more SSS</div></div>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

To learn more about the `valign` attribute: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_valign.asp

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Since you're dealing with table cells, the [`vertical-align`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) property comes into play. This property applies to inline-level and table-cell elements only.

The default value of the `vertical-align` property, [according to the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#line-height), is `baseline`. However, major [browsers tend to use the `middle` value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33487148/3597276) instead.

In any case, the content of your table cell is vertically centered.

You can override this setting with `vertical-align: top`.

More details: [Default value of vertical-align for table cells](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33487148/3597276)